# How to use Web Apis to get data from the server without internet connection in android?

Tags: android, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, web-applications, asp.net-mvc-5

I have created a web application in ASP.NET MVC5 and I want to create an android app for it. If I have a SQL server database in my laptop, is it possible to that I create android project in android studio, connect my phone with laptop, install apk ,and insert/retrieve data to/from my database located on my computer.

I have deployed my web application to a remote server and I know Restful web api's can be used to retrieve data from the server but it will require an internet connection on my phone, right? I have used RESTFUL web api's in my web application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Web Api's to get data from server without internet only in local area connection , in which you have server and your android application linked to some local area network. But if you want to get data from remote servers you have to use Internet connection. Hope this helps.